# How to select year using CalendarView

Tags: android

This calendar allows to change month by using prev and next arrows

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/date_picker_calendar_view"
    style="@style/Widget.MyApplication.CalendarView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_end"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_start"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But how to change only year (fastly), because to change a year I have to change month 12 times?

[image]

Comment: Try tapping on the middle text view, that will give you the list of all the years

Comment: @gtxtreme tried it already, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Material DateTime Picker might be what you're looking for. It offers alot more display options for dates and easier picking of year. I use it instead of CalendarView

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

Comment: I don't want to use any library, I want to use CalendarView in fragment layout

Comment: then you're down to the very little customization option offered by CalendarVIew. Refer here for it : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html

Answer (score 0):

[`DatePickerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker) consists of `CalendarView` underhood, and also provides a year selection feature when you click on year.

[image]